# Select certain blog posts in CSS (Tumblr theme)

Tags: jquery, css

What I have is a big `<article>` tag inside `{block:Posts}`, meaning I stylize `article` to give the posts on my blog theme their style. A problem I encountered using jQuery is that when using `mouseenter` or `mouseleave` on the `<article>` tag, it will select all of the posts on the page (since they are all article) and do what I coded, but to all of them, and not to the specific post I want it to.

Here's my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("article img").mouseenter(function(){
         $("article").css("background-color", "red");
     });
     $("article img").mouseleave(function(){
         $("article").css("background-color", "transparent");
     });
 });
```

What I don't know how to do is target the specific post I'm hovering, and not the whole bunch of posts.

Thank you, and please excuse my newbie jQuery coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reference the specific `article`, you can pass in the `event` (usually referenced simply as `e`) to the mouseenter callback like so:

```
$('article img').mouseenter(function(e) {
    $(e.target).closest('article').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbJGOY

Answer (score 1):

```
$("article img").hover( 
  function(e){
    $(e.target).css("background-color", "red");
   },
   function(e){
     $(e.target).css("background-color", "transparent");
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/ke82ot1v/)**

Comment: Can you please add some explanation to your answer?

Comment: @PiotrWolkowski, In order to use jquery, I would like to wrap it in a jquery object using either $(this) or $(e.target).

Comment: I meant to your answer to improve its quality.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your code to target the specific element you wish to change to red. Currently you are saying when the mouse enters article img you want to make all of the article have a background color red. You could change it to use `this` which would target the article img you selected.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("article img").mouseenter(function(){
         $("this").css("background-color", "red");
     });
     $("article img").mouseleave(function(){
         $("this").css("background-color", "transparent");
     });
 });
```

Have the article images got classes or id's associated with them? If you could provide some html code that would be helpful.